# How to build ros1_bridge in ros2 with locally defined messages

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The instructions for building ros1_bridge in ros2 says "The bridge will be built with support for any message/service packages that are on your path and have an associated mapping between ROS 1 and ROS 2".

How do I defines this mapping? I want to have support for ROS messages that I have defined myself. But just adding my workspace to the paths (including the basg file as the instructions say) only seem to build for the messages in ROS1 kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252446/how-to-build-ros1_bridge-in-ros2-with-locally-defined-messages/) by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2017-01-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rohbotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/23169/rohbotics/) on 2017-01-22**:
Do you have equivalent message files in both your ROS1 (catkin) and ROS2 (ament) workspaces?

**Comment by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) on 2017-01-23**:
No, I have not. So this is probably why it does not work. I thought that the ROS1 messages would automatically be copied to the ROS2. Now it seems I have to duplicate the definition. I will test with copying them to ROS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is that I have to define the messages in ROS2 also. I thought they were automatically generated so that we do not need to have multiple message files. But that was not a correct assumption.

---

Originally posted by [tompe17](https://answers.ros.org/users/22519/tompe17/) with karma: 140 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1